# how can i send email to team members after assigning record in crm 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I need send email to team members.The mail like the record is assigned to you.using either workflow or plugin.which means If I assigned a record to particular team I need  send mail notification  to that particular team members ...how to do this ???

Answer (score 1):

What type of object are you talking about?

For anything that's owned by a user, you can create a workflow that is triggered whenever the object changes owners, the will send an e-mail to the new owner. Not too tricky.

sending an e-mail to an entire team is tricker. There are a couple different ways to accomplish this.

1. Distribution list.

Edit the team entity so that it contains a team e-mail. Create a distribution list that has all the members of the team on it. Create a workflow like you would with a user, and then send an e-mail to the distributon list address if there is a change in ownership

The disadvantage of this is that you have to manage the DL list and the teams in CRM separately. But it's quick.

2. Plug in.

Create a plug in that will fire when the ownership of the object changes. Make a linq query that will grab all the e-mail addresses of the users in the team. Create a foreach loop that will send out the e-mail to all those users.

This is the more difficult and time consuming of the options, but it's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a custom workflow library that can send an email to members of a team.

https://crm2011internalemail.codeplex.com/